# Problems with updatepanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a problem, when i delete a item for example, it deletes from the database, do well the bindGridView(), but dont refresh the screen... what i'm doing wrong?

The other problem is for example when i delete a item i want to show a sucess message, but isnt refreshing with the update panel too..

is the same problem
This is my code:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelListaUsers" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <asp:GridView ID="gridviewListUsers" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowCreated="OnRowCreated"
                                AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" OnSorting="OnSort" DataKeyNames="Id" PageSize="2"
                                CssClass="cssTable" BorderWidth="0" Width="900px" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alternate-row"
                                OnRowCommand="gridviewListUsers_RowCommand" 
                                EmptyDataText="Não existe utilizadores..." 
                                    onpageindexchanging="gridviewListUsers_PageIndexChanging">
                                <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="X-Large" ForeColor="black" />
                                <PagerSettings Mode="Numeric" />
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:BoundField HeaderStyle-CssClass="table-header-repeat line-left minwidth-1" HeaderText="Nome"
                                        DataField="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
                                    <asp:BoundField HeaderStyle-CssClass="table-header-repeat line-left minwidth-1" HeaderText="Username"
                                        DataField="Username" SortExpression="Username" />
                                    <asp:BoundField HeaderStyle-CssClass="table-header-repeat line-left" HeaderText="Email"
                                        DataField="Email" SortExpression="Email" />
                                    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-CssClass="options-width" HeaderStyle-CssClass="table-header-options line-left">
                                        <HeaderTemplate>
                                            <a href="">Opções</a></HeaderTemplate>
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEdit" CommandArgument='<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>' CssClass="icon-1 info-tooltip"
                                                CommandName="edit" ToolTip="Editar" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDelete" CommandArgument='<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>' CssClass="icon-2 info-tooltip"
                                                CommandName="delete" ToolTip="Remover" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                </Columns>
                            </asp:GridView>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelMensagens" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:Panel ID="pnlMessageRed" Visible="false" runat="server">
                                <!--  start message-red -->
                                <div id="message-red">
                                    <table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="red-left">
                                                Erro. Ficou gravado a informação do erro, tente novamente
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="red-right">
                                                <a class="close-red">
                                                    <img src="../images/table/icon_close_red.gif" alt="" /></a>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                                <!--  end message-red -->
                            </asp:Panel>
                            <asp:Panel ID="pnlMessageBlue" Visible="false" runat="server">
                                <!--  start message-blue -->
                                <div id="message-blue">
                                    <table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="blue-left">
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblSucesso" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="blue-right">
                                                <a class="close-blue">
                                                    <img src="../images/table/icon_close_blue.gif" alt="" /></a>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                                <!--  end message-blue -->
                            </asp:Panel>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

this is the gridview code

```
private void bindGridView()
    {
        String strSort = String.Empty;
        if (null != m_strSortExp &&
            String.Empty != m_strSortExp)
        {
            strSort = String.Format("{0} {1}", m_strSortExp, (m_SortDirection == SortDirection.Descending) ? "DESC" : "ASC");
        }
        DataView dv = new DataView(m_dsUsers.Tables[0], String.Empty, strSort, DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
        gridviewListUsers.DataSource = dv;
        gridviewListUsers.DataBind();
        UpdatePanelListaUsers.Update();
    }

protected void OnSort(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        // There seems to be a bug in GridView sorting implementation. Value of
        // SortDirection is always set to "Ascending". Now we will have to play
        // little trick here to switch the direction ourselves.
        if (String.Empty != m_strSortExp)
        {
            if (String.Compare(e.SortExpression, m_strSortExp, true) == 0)
            {
                m_SortDirection =
                    (m_SortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending) ? SortDirection.Descending : SortDirection.Ascending;
            }
        }
        ViewState["_Direction_"] = m_SortDirection;
        ViewState["_SortExp_"] = m_strSortExp = e.SortExpression;
        this.bindGridView();
    }

    void AddSortImage(GridViewRow headerRow)
    {
        Int32 iCol = GetSortColumnIndex(m_strSortExp);
        if (-1 == iCol)
        {
            return;
        }
        // Create the sorting image based on the sort direction.
        Image sortImage = new Image();
        if (SortDirection.Ascending == m_SortDirection)
        {
            sortImage.ImageUrl = "~/images/table/dwn.gif";
            sortImage.AlternateText = "Ordem Ascendente";
        }
        else
        {
            sortImage.ImageUrl = "~/images/table/up.gif";
            sortImage.AlternateText = "Ordem Descendente";
        }

        // Add the image to the appropriate header cell.
        headerRow.Cells[iCol].Controls.Add(sortImage);
    }

    // This is a helper method used to determine the index of the
    // column being sorted. If no column is being sorted, -1 is returned.
    int GetSortColumnIndex(String strCol)
    {
        foreach (DataControlField field in gridviewListUsers.Columns)
        {
            if (field.SortExpression == strCol)
            {
                return gridviewListUsers.Columns.IndexOf(field);
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }

    protected void gridviewListUsers_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "delete")
        {
            try
            {
                //obter o id
                int index = int.Parse((string)e.CommandArgument);
                string key = gridviewListUsers.DataKeys[index]["Id"].ToString();

                //apagar o utilizador
                Project_BLL.Users.RemoveUser(Convert.ToInt32(key));

                //mensagem de sucesso
                pnlMessageRed.Visible = false;
                pnlMessageBlue.Visible = true;
                lblSucesso.Text = "Utilizador adicionado com sucesso. A reencaminhar...";

                //força o update dos users, e nao da cache
                bindGridView();

                GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)(((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
                LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)row.FindControl("lnkDelete");
                if (lb != null)
                {
                    ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(lb);
                }

                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alertUser", "alert('deleted');", true);

            }
            catch (Exception er)
            {
                pnlMessageRed.Visible = true;
                pnlMessageBlue.Visible = false;
            }
        }

        else if (e.CommandName == "edit")
        {
            try
            {
                int index = int.Parse((string)e.CommandArgument);
                string key = gridviewListUsers.DataKeys[index]["Id"].ToString();

                Response.Redirect("EditarUtilizador.aspx?id=" + key);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                pnlMessageRed.Visible = true;
                pnlMessageBlue.Visible = false;
            }
        }

    }

    protected void gridviewListUsers_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        gridviewListUsers.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        gridviewListUsers.SelectedIndex = -1;
        bindGridView(); // Call bind here
    }
```

Comment: Is this a content page of a parent component?  Do you already have ScriptManager defined in the parent? If so, you should use ScriptManagerProxy.

Comment: this is a webform using a masterpage. the scriptmanager is in the masterpage

Comment: In dealing with such scenario's i found it usefull to install fiddler and see the html response you get. Under normal circumstances the response should include all the updatepanels you triggered. Also worth a shot is changing your updateMode to always to see if that works.

Comment: with always in the both updatePanels still dont work :S

Comment: try setting UpdatePanel's UpdateMode as Conditional and updating the UpdatePanel after refreshing the gridview.

Comment: try that, and dont work if i have the gridview .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just changed the CommandName to myEdit and myDelete (like Ashwini Verma suggest before), and now it works.

Then i google it to find why, and seems that that words are reserved

http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/Issue-with-OnRowCommand-event-of-GridView-while-using-reserve-words-in-CommandName-property-935.php

Answer (score 1):

2nd Problem: register the script from code behind

```
protected void gridviewListUsers_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "delete")
        {
            //your code
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alertUser", "alert('deleted');", true);
        }
    }
```

As you are sure your loop going inside CommandName="delete" then javascript alert method should definitely call.

1st problem : set UpdateMode="Conditional" in UpdatePanel and use following approach in your code behind:

```
public UpdatePanelUpdateMode UpdateMode
{
    get { return this.UpdatePanelListaUsers.UpdateMode; }
    set { this.UpdatePanelListaUsers.UpdateMode = value; }
}
public void Update()
{
    this.UpdatePanelListaUsers.Update();
    //your girdview bind method.
    bindGridView()
}
```

Now just call bindGridView() any where you want to get refresh updatepanel.

Comment: the commandName is right, but about the 2nd problem, after my post i tried this, i think is the same thing

Comment: GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)(((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
                    LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)row.FindControl("lnkDelete");
                    if (lb != null)
                    {
                        ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(lb);
                    }

Comment: but i insert it and dont happend anything. Just update the code

Comment: did you try registering script if so, I edited my answer how to do? and have you checked changing "CommandName" other than delete and edit?

Comment: the commandName is working because inside the debug goes there

Comment: Ashwini Verma that didnt work too... but i tried to change the commandName to myedit like you sugest, just in last attemp, and to my astonishment it work (but with the name (edit and delete) entered into the cycle, should be with some reserved words i think).. but now it works.. thanks a lot for the help..

Comment: change the awnser like you have the first time so i can put it like the awnser :)

Comment: i tried your first suggestion (changed the command name to mydelete for example) and it worked. it seems that delete and edit and reserved words and because that the grid dont refresh http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/Issue-with-OnRowCommand-event-of-GridView-while-using-reserve-words-in-CommandName-property-935.php

Comment: congrats! that's why asked you before whether your flow going inside e.CommandName event or not.

Comment: thanks, but the flow was going inside, doing the action to delete a item, the only problem was not refresh the gridview..